# Problem with normals...what else?

Tags: mesh, normals

When I try to remesh, I see this

> QuadriFlow: The mesh needs to be manifold and have face normals that point in a consistent direction.

It won't let me remesh. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> won't work and in *Face Orientation* all I see is red (as per pic). What can I do?

Thanks[image]

Comment: Try scale -1 in edit mode.

Comment: @lemon ??? How does it differs from Shift+N? Any reason why Shift+N would not work in edit mode with all vertices selected? Thank you

Comment: @vklidu sometimes there are conflicts that make so shift+N fails (I don't say this is the case here or the OP forget to check invert, for instance; don't know). But when it fails that can be an alternative.

Comment: Recalculating normals can fail if the mesh is non-manifold and Blender gets confused between the interior and exterior. Another way to fix it is to select the red mesh in edit mode, use Shift+N and check *Inside* in the popup box.

Comment: @lemon  what do you mean? like the all object scaled down of one?

Comment: @stphnl329 i've tried without success

Comment: @user89328, I suggest scaling minus one S -1 in edit mode.

Comment: If none of the suggested works, you should upload your file using this site https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and copy the link here.

Comment: @lemon scaling to minus one on each axis did the trick. obvs then you have to rotate and move the object, but great!!! Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to first *Voxel Remesh* it at something like 0.1m, then all of the normals were fixed, I clicked *Quad* and everything worked fine.